# Ant Design, Hide Pagination when there is the only page

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

According to the documentation ([first FAQ of Table documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-pagination)) I have the next code:

```
<Table
    key={index + plant.name}
    columns={setColumns(plant.name, plant.id)}
    data={setData(plant)}
    pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 10, hideOnSinglePage: true }}
  />
```

But it is still appearing the pagination:

[image: But it is still appearing the pagination:]

Also I have tried all combinations as:

- pagination={{false}}
- pagination={false}
- pagination={"false"}

But nothing runs properly. Could you help me please?
Currently to testing the maximum number of values are 4 into the table.

The config that I am using:

- MacOS Version 10.15.6 (19G2021)
- Ant Design Version ^4.5.4
- React ^16.13.1

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: pagination={false} working fine  in 4.5.4 version,

Comment: I can promise you that "pagination={false}" not runs :(

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackantdtablepagination-scdd9?file=/index.js  i made this codesandbox with and without pagination.. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can try checking the length of data which is rendered in your list, If the data length exceeds perPageRecord than you can show.

```
 pagination={data.length > perPageRecord  && { defaultPageSize: 10, hideOnSinglePage: true }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i check the antd portal found out , if want to disabled the display of pagination, need to control the position of the pagination.

position: ['none', 'none']

first one is top, second one is bottom

you can add more condition for display

for more detail: https://ant.design/components/table/

```
<Table column={yourColumn} dataSource={yourDataSource} pagination={{ position: ['none', 'none'] }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today we may use `hideOnSinglePage` option ([FAQ](https://ant.design/components/table/#How-to-hide-pagination-when-single-page-or-no-data)):

```html
<Table
  columns={COLUMNS}
  dataSource={data}
  pagination={{ pageSize: PAGE_SIZE, hideOnSinglePage: true }}
/>
```